# Is there a name for spaces that always have local sections?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology

Given a continuous map $p:E \rightarrow B$

Suppose for every point $b \in B$ and a point $x \in p^{-1}b$ in the fibre of it, there is an open set $V$ of $B$ that contains the point $b$ such that there is a local section of $p$ from  $V$ and that goes through $x$.

Is there a name for a standard name for spaces with this property?

Etale spaces, it seems to me, always have this property; but I don't think they are characterised by it.

Comment: Do you mean "which maps p have this property"?

Comment: @studiosus:well, to be precise yes.

Comment: Then etale spaces do have this property, but so do fiber bundles. Your question is roughly about hybrids of the two notions.

Comment: @studiosus: in a sense, yes; in locally trivial [fibre bundles](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+bundle) one can always locally lift through every point in a fibre; we don't need the fibre to be typical here so the same holds for locally trivial bundles; but for general fibre bundles or just bundles this won't hold.

Comment: By fiber bundle I mean loc triv one.

Comment: @studiosus: i thought as much; but then we have the inclusion of notions as fibre bundles < etale spaces < above notion; as you wrote 'hybrid' I supposed the loc.triv condition might be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

In the category of smooth manifolds you get a nice answer: You class of maps equals the class of submersions. But this fails in TOP and PL category if E has dimension 2 or more.

Here is another example to consider: the map $p(x,y)=x+y$, restricted to the algebraic subset $xy=0$: it satisfies your condition.